# how to Spring-data MongoDB @prepersist @preupdate without using JPA

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want to learn, is it possible to use @prepersist/@preupdate like annotations in spring-data-mongodb documents i mean is it possible to make modifications before save or before update?
I look forward documentation of  [spring data mongodb](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.0.0.M5/reference/html/)  There is a listener BeforeConvertListener, but i want to use without listener, inside @document object just put an annotation to attributes. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution, but just related with my problem. 
My problem was i need to prepresist or preupdate modificationDates, insertDates. So spring-data can provide annotations for them :

```
@CreatedDate -> insertDate ( prepersist )
@LastModifiedDate -> updateDate ( preupdate )
```

Comment: how can this work? does mongo have entity listeners?